# when i tried to get the textview value in Fragment from mainactivity, my app is not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

// This is the Mainactivity java class, here i am getting the edittext value from username

```
public class Home_Foodcourt extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText username,userpassword;
    Button user_login;
    TextView user_register;
    FoodCourt_UserLoginDatabase foodCourt_userDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home__foodcourt);
        foodCourt_userDatabase=new FoodCourt_UserLoginDatabase(this);

        username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        userpassword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginpassword);
        user_login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login_submit);
        user_register= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_newregister);
        user_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Home_Foodcourt.this,FoodCourt_Register.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        user_login.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String name=username.getText().toString();
        String password=userpassword.getText().toString();
       String Admin="aDminSN";
        String Pass= foodCourt_userDatabase.Login(name);

      if(password.equals(Pass))   //
        {
               Message.message(this,"Log in Successfully");
            Intent i=new Intent(Home_Foodcourt.this,Userhome.class);
            i.putExtra("Username",name);
            startActivity(i);

            }else
            {
                Message.message(this,"Login Failed");
            }

    }
```

//This is Home Fragment that i want to get that string from Mainactivity, but my app is crashed. it is not getting the value from that main activity

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView textView;

        public HomeFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            Bundle bundle=getArguments();
          View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
            textView.setText("Welcome to FoodCourt"+"username");
          return rootView;
        }

    }
```

can you please check where i am getting issue and please helpme to get the value properly

Comment: Can you post your logcat from the crash?

Comment: Where does it crash and which Exception rises? Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dell.foodcourt/com.example.dell.foodcourt.Userhome}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: These two comments that i am getting

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45883159/edit) to include the logcat rather than post it as a comment? Just makes it easier for us to read and understand it.

Comment: this line `textView.setText("Welcome to FoodCourt"+"username");` The textView is not initialized so it is `null`.
`TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);` should initialize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass strings such as names/emails etc it's quite easy to use a custom sharedPreferences class. Say you want to pass a string *name* from Fragment A to Activity B, and also access *name* in fragments B and C, you could do all this using a local sharedPreferences class. I'll post example code for you below.

The custom SharedPreferences class (call it UserDetails or something):

```
public class UserDetails{
static final String SharedPrefUserName = ""; //default value can go in between " ".
static final String SharedPrefUserOtherData = ""; 

//the bit below gets the shared preferences
public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx)
{
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
}

//This sets a string value
public static void setLoggedInUserName(Context ctx, String name)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.putString(SharedPrefUserName, name);
    editor.commit();
}

//this retrieves a string value
public static String getLoggedInUserName(Context ctx)
{
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(SharedPrefUserName, "");
}


}
```

To set the credentials you would use:

```
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

String name = username.getText().toString();

// If you called your shared prefs 'UserDetails', storing the name would look like this:

UserDetails.setLoggedInUserName(getApplicationContext(), name);
```

Then to retrieve the stored data, and set a textView (lets call it 'userNameTextView') we do this:

```
Textview usernameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);

String userStoredName = UserDetails.getLoggedInUserName(getActivity());

userNameTextView.setText(userStoredName);
```

EDIT: You can do this without creating a new class for the SharedPreferences. The code below is the same as yours, just corrected with the SharedPreferences implemented.

To insert a string into shared prefs, using your String.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Name",name);
editor.apply();
```

This puts your value for 'name' that you got through your EditText (using getText().toString()). Now to access 'name' from your fragment, you can do this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String name = preferences.getString("Name", "");
```

Note how "Name" is used here just as with the first bit of code, this is called a 'key', which is part of a 'key-value pair'. You need a key to access the string that is stored in the preferences. This way you can have any number of key-value pairs saved (e.g. name, age, email, DoB, country etc.) AND access them anywhere within the app. Make sure not to save passwords in shared prefs though.

To make this easier for you to understand, I'll rewrite the code you posted to include this, and highlight it with comments.

Your Main Activity (the first one):

```
public class Home_Foodcourt extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText username,userpassword;
Button user_login;
TextView user_register;
FoodCourt_UserLoginDatabase foodCourt_userDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home__foodcourt);
    foodCourt_userDatabase=new FoodCourt_UserLoginDatabase(this);

    username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    userpassword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginpassword);
    user_login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login_submit);
    user_register= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_newregister);

    user_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Home_Foodcourt.this,FoodCourt_Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    user_login.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    String name=username.getText().toString();

    //############ I've added the section below. ###########
    SharedPreferences preferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Name",name);
    editor.apply();
    //############ SharedPref section complete. ############

    String password=userpassword.getText().toString();
   String Admin="aDminSN";
    String Pass= foodCourt_userDatabase.Login(name);

  if(password.equals(Pass))   //
    {
           Message.message(this,"Log in Successfully");
        Intent i=new Intent(Home_Foodcourt.this,Userhome.class);
        i.putExtra("Username",name);
        startActivity(i);

        }else
        {
            Message.message(this,"Login Failed");
        }

}
```

Now for the fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private TextView textView;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
      View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

        // ####### ALWAYS initialise your view components like below ##
        TextView welcomeMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PUT_TEXTVIEW_ID_HERE);

        // ###### The section below fetches the 'name' value from the first activity ###
        SharedPreferences preferences = 
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        String username = preferences.getString("Name", "DEFAULT_STRING");
         /*You can change DEFAULT_STRING to be any string you want. If there 
         isn't any data to pull from SharedPrefs, it will show this string instead!*/
        // ###################


        textView.welcomeMessage("Welcome to FoodCourt " + username);
      return rootView;
    }

}
```

I haven't tested this and have just written it in the browser, but it's very similar to what I use in my current project so I'm confident that it'll work for you. Just comment if it doesn't work, but try to provide error codes and give something for me to work with.

Comment: As slipped_disk mentioned, you didn't intialise the TextView within your fragment. You need to do this within the class to be able to access it. The first line of the third segment of code that I posted shows you how you should initialise a TextView (or any other view, just like you did with your EditText and Buttons in your MainActivity).

Comment: Hi stewart,  really thanks for your help but I want to get that by using sqlite database... Can you please suggest in my code.... That will be helpful to mw

Comment: You'll need some sort of reference data stored in your app that allows you to retrieve related data from the database. I.e if you want to search your database for the email of the user, you'll need something like their name or user_id stored in the app to refer to the table using a SELECT FROM query. Does that make sense?

Comment: As an alternative for this, if you simply initialise your TextView within the fragment (do it after the inflator method), you should be able to call setText on it using the username key from your first activity.

Comment: Did you create a new java class and fill it with the shared preferences info? If you're struggling with creating a new class to modify the preferences, I'll update my answer to include a direct method without an added class.

Comment: Hi Steward, may be this answer is useful for people who used sharedpreferences so i want to accept this answer is helpful. :)

Comment: Did it work for you? Cheers for accepting it though, hopefully it can help others

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an intent to start the class Userhome.class, does this exist?

When you are setting text in the textView.setText() method you are setting it to the string "username" not the username that you are requiring from the bundle, to do this you can use:

```
bundle.getString(“Username“)
```

Comment: i used fragment classes usage logic in Userhome.java... and i am using the text intent in Fragment may be that is throwing error.

Comment: You have not initialized textView before using the method setText() on it.

Comment: Can you please help me where I can initialize that textview

Comment: I initialize that Textview In home fragment and it is also not working

Comment: You have to set the textView equal to a TextView like you done in Home_Foodcourt:

    user_register= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_newregister);

Comment: Please note that your intent is not starting HomeFragment, it is starting Userhome.class.

Comment: Yes in  my home javaclass I mentioned that.. .i started that intent from userhome only

Comment: Textview to textview = epicure. Findviewbyid(R.id.hometext); but still app is crashing.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand: Textview to textview = epicure. Findviewbyid(R.id.hometext);

Comment: Textview textview = rootview. Findviewbyid(R.id.hometext);