# Updating Shared Preferences while updating user information

Tags: java, android

I am using a Shared preferences class to hold the information of the user after login, for later updating I am using the information I have kept in the Share preferences class but when I update user information I have to log out from the profile and then log in the see the changes. Can anyone help me to in how to change the information in the SharedPrefManager class while I update the user info? Bellow is the SharedPrefManager Class and user updating Class.

```
public class SharedPrefManager {

    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "mysharedpref";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_USER_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_USER_DESCRIPTION = "description";


    private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;

    }

    public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public boolean userLogin(int id, String name, String email , String description){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt(KEY_USER_ID, id);
        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, name);
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_EMAIL, email);
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_DESCRIPTION, description);
        editor.apply();

        return true;
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null) != null){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean logout(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    }


    public String getUsername(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null);
    }

    public String getUserEmail(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_EMAIL, null);
    }

    public String getUserDesc(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_DESCRIPTION, null);
    }


}
```

This the User Updating Class.

```
public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText name, description;
    String email;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Button update, delete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDes);
        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editUpdate);
        delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DeletePro);
        name.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUsername());
        description.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserDesc());
        email = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserEmail();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        update.setOnClickListener(this);
        delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void updateUser() {
        final String username = name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc = description.getText().toString().trim();


        if (username == "" || desc.length()>100) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid User Name or Description is exceeding thr limit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            progressDialog.setMessage("Updating Information ...");
            progressDialog.show();
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    Constants.URL_updatePro,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            progressDialog.hide();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("name", username);
                    params.put("email", email);
                    params.put("description", desc);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            finish();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == update) {
            updateUser();
        }
        if (v == delete)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(EditProfile.this, DeleteProfile.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: [Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883159/when-i-tried-to-get-the-textview-value-in-fragment-from-mainactivity-my-app-is/45883962?noredirect=1#comment78744252_45883962)

I showed a guy how to implement sharedPrefs, It's fairly simple to update the preferences and every time you re-initialize an activity or fragment your code should automatically retrieve whatever is stored in the SharedPrefs. That means that if you update the user's name in Activity A, when you load Activity B, it will fetch the sharedPrefs and find this new name (Assuming your getSharedPrefs code is within the onCreate or onResume method for your fragments/activities).

If you're not seeing the sharedPrefs info update within your activity, it may be because the activity is not refreshing (either because you haven't told it to, or because something has broken). You could try adding a 'refresh' button to the activity to test this, which would restart the activity, rather than logging out/in - which does the same thing as refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

I think here u getting the update profile info.

```
 @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", username);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("description", desc);
                name.setText(username);
                description.setText(desc);
                return params;
            }
```

Hope this will work

Comment: sorry to say, Shared preference have no auto call method. U have to do everything by u ..